# How to get rid of promise when getting json data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to simply get data from a weather API. Here's my api link to get http://api.wunderground.com/api/5b81d144ae2d1942/conditions/q/46.838260,-71.293689.json

In my api.js file, i have this basic function :

```
const baseUrl = `http://api.wunderground.com/api/5b81d144ae2d1942/conditions/q`;

export const getCurrent = (lat,lon) => {
  return fetch(`${baseUrl}/${lon},${lat}.json`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json.current_observation.weather)
      return json.current_observation
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.error('unable to fetch tasks')
    })
}
```

Notice the console.log, in this function i'm able to fetch the json data, i got the value i want.

Now, in my Vue, i call this function this way :

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    current: []
  }),
  created: function () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showPosition(position) {
      const data = api.getCurrent(position.coords.longitude,position.coords.latitude);
      this.current = data;
      console.log(this.current);
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, the console.log in here gives me this :

```
Promise {<pending>}__proto__: 
Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
```

I don't know what's going on but i can't access the data. I searched on the net, a lot of pages talk about this, but couldn't find the exact solution, only long texts ...

Is there a solution for this (code please)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "get rid" of the `Promise` and access it's data, use [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) in `.getCurrent()`'s result, just like you are when using `fetch()`:

```
  methods: {
    showPosition(position) {
      api.getCurrent(position.coords.longitude,position.coords.latitude)
        .then((data) => {
          this.current = data;
          console.log(this.current);
        }
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you could declare `showPosition` as [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function), and use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
  methods: {
    showPosition: async function(position) {
      const data = await api.getCurrent(position.coords.longitude,position.coords.latitude);
      this.current = data;
      console.log(this.current);
    }
  }
```

Just keep in mind the results of **both** executions will be processed asynchronously, meaning `this.current` will not have the value of `data` right away.